# Problems with accents using php and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have to read a txt file which text has accents such as á or ñ, so I wrote this php code to read the file:

```
<p id="text1">
    <?php
        $fopen = fopen("../curriculums/es.txt", "r");
        $texte = fread($fopen, filesize("../curriculums/es.txt"));
        fclose($fopen);
        echo $texte;
    ?>
</p>
```

But when it has to write a "ó", it writes this: "Ã³". It's possible to solve this with php or jquery?

Comment: What is the charset attribute of your page?

Comment: UTF-8, I've also tried with utf-7 and iso but it didn't work eigther.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, CollinD, I've revised and in the charset line there was an error. Now it works, I put utf-8

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest setting the `charset` meta attribute of your page to something appropriate (probably UTF-8) with the following code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    ...
</head>
```